# Proper hexadecimal conversion to text/ascii

Tags: javascript, utf-8, bluetooth, hex, decoding

Trying to figure out how to get my qr scanners to output text to be used in my website.
My qr reader is outputting text that needs to be rendered with event.target.value.getuint***someintegerhere***. I cannot get this to convert to text unless I plop it into some hex decoder online.

I do notice the comment about using TextDecoder to process the data, but it still sort of takes me back to the same place off not really understanding what's going on with this sort of thing...

For example

`0x6d 0x6f 0x6f 0x0d` should read 'moo'

I understand that the encoding is "utf-8" but not what that means or how to modify the code so that it outputs things correctly...

Here's a chunk of the code that seems to be where i need the most help:

```js
function handleNotifications(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  let a = [];
  // Convert raw data bytes to hex values just for the sake of showing something.
  // In the "real" world, you'd use data.getUint8, data.getUint16 or even
  // TextDecoder to process raw data bytes.
  for (let i = 0; i < value.byteLength; i++) {
    a.push('0x' + ('00' + value.getUint8(i).toString(16)).slice(-2));
  }
  log(hex2ascii('> ' + a.join(' ')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handleNotifications(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  let a = [];
  // Convert raw data bytes to hex values just for the sake of showing something.
  // In the "real" world, you'd use data.getUint8, data.getUint16 or even
  // TextDecoder to process raw data bytes.
  for (let i = 0; i < value.byteLength; i++) {
    a.push('0x' + ('00' + value.getUint8(i).toString(16)).slice(-2));
  }
  log(hex2ascii('> ' + a.join(' ')));
}

function hex2ascii(hexString) {
  const numberArray =  hexString.slice(2) // Get the string without the first two characters (removes '> ')
    .split(' ') // Split the string on spaces.
    .map(hex => Number(hex)); // Create a new array where each element of the hex array is converted to a JavaScript Number
  
  // Now we have an array of Numbers.
  
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(numberArray); // Make an array of bytes from the number array This is necessary to use the TextDecoder.
  
  const string = (new TextDecoder()).decode(byteArray); // Create a TextDecoder, and decode the byte array to get a string.
  
  return string;
}

console.log(hex2ascii("> 0x6d 0x6f 0x6f 0x0d"));
```

This snippet only logs the received data every 2 messages, concatenating the data received between them. For example, if the first message said `moo`, and the second message said  `I'm a cow!`, the text `moo I'm a cow!` would be logged after receiving the second message.

```js
let messageCount = 0;

let currentMessage = "";

function handleNotifications(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  let a = [];
  // Convert raw data bytes to hex values just for the sake of showing something.
  // In the "real" world, you'd use data.getUint8, data.getUint16 or even
  // TextDecoder to process raw data bytes.
  for (let i = 0; i < value.byteLength; i++) {
    a.push('0x' + ('00' + value.getUint8(i).toString(16)).slice(-2));
  }
  
  currentMessage += hex2ascii('> ' + a.join(' '));
  
  if (messageCount < 1) messageCount++;
  else {
    messageCount = 0;
    log(currentMessage);
    currentMessage = "";
  }
}

function hex2ascii(hexString) {
  const numberArray =  hexString.slice(2) // Get the string without the first two characters (removes '> ')
    .split(' ') // Split the string on spaces.
    .map(hex => Number(hex)); // Create a new array where each element of the hex array is converted to a JavaScript Number
  
  // Now we have an array of Numbers.
  
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(numberArray); // Make an array of bytes from the number array This is necessary to use the TextDecoder.
  
  const string = (new TextDecoder()).decode(byteArray); // Create a TextDecoder, and decode the byte array to get a string.
  
  return string;
}

console.log(hex2ascii("> 0x6d 0x6f 0x6f 0x0d"));
```

Comment: This worked so well! My only issue now is that it seems to be sending two 16bit messages as output, so it can’t capture the full value of the url I’m trying to send… do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: @muhareb If I understand you correctly, it now seems to be sending 2 separate messages, but you want to concatanate the data and handle it at the same time?

Comment: @muhareb I added a snippet for what I assume is your situation. Please correct me if I assumed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can all be vastly simplified

```js
const h2a = str => str && str.replace(/ ?0x/g,"") // get rid of the space and 0x
  .match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}/g) // get the 00-FF parts
  .map(v => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v, 16))) // convert each to in using hex radix and get the ascii from the int
  .join(''); // string them together
document.getElementById("hex")
  .addEventListener("input", e => document.getElementById("ascii").value = h2a(e.target.value))
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="hex" /> Hex (paste or scan - for example cut and paste 0x6d 0x6f 0x6f 0x0d)
<hr/>
<input type="text" value="" id="ascii" /> Ascii
```